# HTTP 400 Error: size is too accurate. Smallest unit is 0.00000001

Tags: coinbase-api

i am making a call to

```
authedClient.placeOrder(sellParams)
```

with params:

```
sellParams:any = {
    'side': 'sell',
    'product_id': 'BTC-USD',
    'type': ‘market’,
    ’size’: 0.012613515
}
```

this throws error:

```
Error: HTTP 400 Error: size is too accurate. Smallest unit is 0.00000001
    at Request._callback (/srv/node_modules/coinbase-pro/lib/clients/public.js:68:15)
    at Request.self.callback (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
```

i am not sure why it fails. Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that you should only place the size that is the increments of `0.00000001` (the `base_increment` below). While your `size` is at precision 9: `0.012613515`, it is rejected.

Currently, I cannot find the `base_increment` in the `/products` endpoint, but in the `status` channel:

```
// Status Message
{
    "type": "status",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": "BTC-USD",
            "base_currency": "BTC",
            "quote_currency": "USD",
            "base_min_size": "0.001",
            "base_max_size": "70",
            "base_increment": "0.00000001", // Here you go
            "quote_increment": "0.01",
            "display_name": "BTC/USD",
            "status": "online",
            "status_message": null,
            "min_market_funds": "10",
            "max_market_funds": "1000000",
            "post_only": false,
            "limit_only": false,
            "cancel_only": false
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you explain how the size should be amended?

Answer (score -1):

I can add an update this, definitely the order float algebra is a little wonky and differs by exchange.  For CB/CB Pro you'll want to get info on your `base_increment` for sell orders and `quote_increment` for buy orders, in string format, run a function like this:

```
def get_increments(ticker, auth_client):
    products = auth_client.get_products()
    for i in range(len(products)):
        if products[i]['id'] == ticker:
            base_incr = products[i]['base_increment']
            quote_incr = products[i]['quote_increment']
    return base_incr, quote_incr
```

i.  Next, you'll want to utilize those increments to round down.  I divide by the appropriate increment, use floor division by 1, then multiply by the same increment.

ii.  To be safe, I get a decimal count again using string manipulation functions, and run something like `round(qty, decimals)`.  This cleans up the occasional lagging string of 9999999 or else 00000001.

iii.  If you're looking to trade with 100% equity, use the `funds` argument in buy (quote asset value), and `size` argument in sell (base asset value).
Buy code looks something like:

```
decimals = int(str(quote_incr).find('1'))-int(str(quote_incr).find('.'))
quote_incr = float(quote_incr)
qty = (qty/quote_incr//1)*quote_incr            
qty = str(round(qty,decimals))
auth_client.place_market_order(product_id=ticker, side='buy', funds=qty)
```

While sell code looks something like:

```
decimals = int(str(base_incr).find('1'))-int(str(base_incr).find('.'))
base_incr = float(base_incr_
qty = (qty/base_incr//1)*base_incr            
qty = str(round(qty,decimals))
auth_client.place_market_order(product_id=ticker, side='buy', size=qty)
```